# How to make the 'href' attribute in HTML dynamic?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

**Explanation :**

1. I have a 'java.util.list' in JSP that contains words.
2. I have another 'java.util.list' in JSP that contains URL links corresponding to 
   each word.
3. I need to display these words on same JSP page and on clicking, they should open their corresponding links.

**Following is my code attempt :**

```
<html>
    <head>
       <style>
           .container{color:blue;}
           #text{width:50%;}
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <form action="" method="get" >
            <label>Node Path:</label>
            <input id="text" type="text" name ="path" />
            <input type= "submit" value="submit" />
            </form>
        </div>
        <div>
            <br>
             <br>
            <%!  String absolutePath;  %>

            <%    
                com.intel.package1.HelloService service = sling.getService(                         com.intel.package1.HelloService.class);

               String path = request.getParameter("path") ;

               if (path != null){
                    java.util.List nodeNames = service.getNodeNames(path);
                  java.util.List nodePaths= service.getNodePaths(path);
                  java.util.List nodeDepths = service.getNodeDepths(path);

                  for (int i=0;i<nodeNames.size();i++){
                      int depth = (int)nodeDepths.get(i);
                      for(int j=0;j<depth;j++){
                           out.println("&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp");
                      }
                      absolutePath= "http://localhost:4502/crx/de/index.jsp#"+nodePaths.get(i);
                      String start = "<a href='' onclick='fns()'>";
                      out.println(start+nodeNames.get(i)+"</a>"  );
                      out.println("<br>");

                      // for(int j=0;j<depth;j++){
                      //   out.println("&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp");
                      // }
                      //  out.println(absolutePath);
                      out.println("<br>");
                      // out.println("<br>");
                }
            }
            %>
        </div>
        <script>
            function fns (){

                var value= "<%=absolutePath%>";
                //alert('hello');

                window.open(value, '_blank');
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try something? You can post that here to get the solution.

Comment: I wanted to keep it clean and concise. But sure will post it.

Comment: @SameerSah Try to indent the code correctly next time (I do it quickly in the editor, so not perfect), this will be much more readable, same thing about 10 empty line that is not necessary.

Comment: First, the JS function is using a JSP tag, so the absolutePath will be the one during the creation of the page. You can't expect to use JSP to do some dynamic input based on the client on the same page. Just pass a parameter to this function, either an index linked to an array (build with JSP) or directly the link you want. But I don't get why you can't simply put the value in the href/value. PS : Please look into Servlet and JSTL. This could be some much shorter with that

Comment: @AxelH Will keep it in mind. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to make the 'href' attribute in HTML dynamic?

Well, you have a variable with the value you want …

> ```
> absolutePath= "http://localhost:4502/crx/de/index.jsp#"+nodePaths.get(i);
> String start = "<a href='' onclick='fns()'>";
> ```

… so just use it:

```
String start = "<a href='" + absolutePath +"'>";
```